# SQL Trigger to validate before inserting values giving error

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle11g

I wrote a trigger for a table in my database in Oracle Express Edition, that has two attributes: room_id, roll_no. room_id is referenced from another table called ROOM, roll_no is referenced from another table called STUDENT.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "STUDENT_ROOM_T1" 
BEFORE
insert on "STUDENT_ROOM"
for each row
begin
DECLARE
room_change_limit EXCEPTION;
capacity_exceeding EXCEPTION;

BEGIN

IF((select no_of_room_changes_this_year from student where roll_no = :NEW.roll_no) = 2)
THEN
RAISE room_change_limit;
END IF;

IF((select count(roll_no) from student_room where room_id = :NEW.room_id group by room_id) + 1 > (select capacity from room where room_id = :NEW.room_id))
THEN
RAISE capacity_exceeding;
END IF;

update student
set no_of_room_changes_this_year = no_of_room_changes_this_year + 1
where roll_no = :NEW.roll_no;

EXCEPTION

WHEN room_change_limit THEN
Raise_application_error(-20324, 'Student has reached room change limit for this year!');

WHEN capacity_exceeding THEN
Raise_application_error(-20326, 'Capacity of room has been reached! Please try another room.');

end;
/
ALTER TRIGGER  "STUDENT_ROOM_T1" ENABLE;
```

I have got two errors:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following: ( - + 
case mod new not null
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following: . ( * @ % & - + ; /
at for mod remainder rem and or group having intersect minus order start uni
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here and how to correct it? I can't understand why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF statement doesn't accepts subselect like that. Declare a variable, do a SELECT INTO and then perform the IF test.

Example:

```
DECLARE
 v_no_of_room_changes_this_year NUMBER;
BEGIN

 SELECT no_of_room_changes_this_year INTO v_no_of_room_changes_this_year 
 FROM student WHERE roll_no = :NEW.roll_no;

 IF( v_no_of_room_changes_this_year  = 2 )
 THEN
  RAISE room_change_limit;
 END IF;

...
```

Comment: Deleted the previous comment, as it was an irrelevant error, and I managed to fix it. My trigger now works, thank you!